# Simple problem with phasors

Tags: math, phasor

I'm trying to solve the following question (a):
[image]

According to the solutions manual and wolfram the answer is:

http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%285-6i%29-%282%2B8i%29%29%2F%28%28-3%2B4i%29%285-i%29%2B%284-6i%29%29

[http://imgur.com/CyFHil4](https://imgur.com/CyFHil4)

This is what I've done:
[image]

I'm not getting the right answer and I don't understand why. I'm following the phasor multiplication and division rules:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Theory/Phasor_Arithmetic

I'm using the fx-300MS for all polar and rectangular conversions.

EDIT: I've tried using exact values, but same problem.

Comment: [This part](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283-14i%29%2F%28-6%2B17i%29) is already wrong, so the error is before. The denominator simplifies to [-7+17j](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28-3%2B4i%29%285-i%29%2B%284-6i%29%29) instead. Off by one :-) I don't see the point of converting the denominator back and for between cathesian and polar forms.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Right. Somehow the denominator should be -7 + j17 (solution manual: imgur.com/CyFHil4 )

Comment: Well, yeah -15+4+4=-7. A lot less to caclulate too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yo had the denominator wrong as it should have been -7 + j17 instead of -6 + j17. I don't quite see the point of converting it back and forth between Cartesian and polar forms; you can calculate it directly will less work; and obviously (-3*5)+4+4=-7.

Your error however is a lot more trivial than that, you carried over a 4 to a 5:

[image]

Comment: I see how you get -7 + j17 by distribution. Why don't we get the same result when we pass through polar form though? When two polar form phasors are multiplied, we multiply their magnitude and add their angles. Why isn't this working here? I feel like I'm missing something very basic here.

Comment: @Georan: Yes. :-)